# Maya polyInfo -ve return the wrong values

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm slowly learning my way through python and Maya, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

So, for some reason, when I use polyInfo, it returns the wrong information. 
Example, on the basic plane, I select one vertice and execute the following command.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.polyInfo(ve = True)
```

It returns

```
# Result: [u'VERTEX     48:     93     90     72     92 \n'] #
```

Those vertices aren't relative at all to the one I selected. Hell, sometimes, it returns non-existing vertices, depending on the selected one.

I don't know if relevant, but I have the same result in MEL with

```
polyInfo -ve
```

The doc isn't useful to me and I have a hard time finding someone with a similar problem.

What's the deal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to query ? Can you give an example of your script.

The flag -ve return from maya documentation : Returns the Edges connected to a vertex. Requires vertices to be selected.
http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/polyInfo.html

Are you feeding the command with a selection : i.e :

```
edges = cmds.polyInfo("pPlane1.vtx[48]", ve=True)
```

so it is giving as output : **`'VERTEX    48:'`** selection is vertex number 48 (a single one at the moment), **`'     93     90     72     92 '`** and it is connected to 4 edges with the indexes : 93, 90,72,92

EDIT :

here is an example code to select the edges:

```
edges = cmds.polyInfo(['pPlane1.vtx[54]', 'pPlane1.vtx[43]'], ve=True)
selOut = []
for i in edges:
    # split the indexes
    indexes = i.split(':')[-1].split(' \n')[0].split('    ')[1:]
    # write as : pPlane1.e[]
    selEdges = ['pPlane1.e[{}]'.format(j.replace(' ','')) for j in indexes]
    # merge the selection
    selOut+=selEdges
# remove duplicated edges :
newSel = list(set(selOut))
cmds.select(newSel)
```

Comment: I feel like an amateur (I'm one, but like an ignorant one). For some reason, I tought  that polyInfo -ve returns the vertices that compose the edges connected to the original vertice. So of course the indexes were false. Should've read the doc more carefully. I tried again, but considering edges, and it makes total sense now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you want the current selection of vertices, you can use cmds.ls(sl=True, fl=True), the fl is just to make on sel per vertex

Comment: In general, `polyInfo` is the last thing you want  for this kind of thing because it returns a string you have to pares.  If you want to get the edges from a vertex, `cmds.polyListConmponentConverstion( your_vert_here, fv=True, te=True)` will give you the same info without the song and dance